# Pressing Tab key does not select next control

Tags: c#, winforms

I have four text boxes in my winform, and I've already ordered their tab index sequentially. Also, I set their `TabStop` properties as `true`. But when I press `Tab` key while in filling my first textbox, it does not move to next one. For that, I even added the following part for each of them in the code:

```
firstTextbox.KeyDown += (sender, args) => 
{
    if(args.KeyCode == Keys.Tab)
    {
        firstTextbox.SelectNextControl(this, true, true, true, true);
    }
}
```

But this didn't help either. Any suggestion?

Comment: [How to: Set the Tab Order on Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bd16a8cw(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: OK, obvious question, but is the TAB key working on your keyboard?

Comment: Sure, it works well.

Comment: First - remove the code you added.  Tabbing should work "out of the box".  Look for any other key handling code in your form.

Comment: Sorry but just because it didn't work "out of the box" I had to choose to write code for it. I tried almost all other methods mentioned on the net but couldn't help.

Comment: Go to *View* menu and select *Tab Order*. What do you see?

Comment: Create a new project, add four textboxes to the form, hit run.  If it works, see what the differences are.  If not, you've got bigger issues.

Comment: Is `textBox1_KeyDown` fired when you press Tab? At least for me, textBox1_KeyDown is never fired and it moves to the next control. It does fire when I press other keys.

Comment: For the tab to fire `KeyDown` you have to override `IsInputKey `.

Comment: If you wrote code to 'fix' something, maybe it wasn't really broken before but is now.. What code did you write?? A `ProcessCmdKey` perhaps?

Comment: @valter: it shows me the tab index order exactly the same as I set to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I was able to fire `textBox1_KeyDown` with the Tab key was by overriding `IsInputKey` method.

```
class TabTextBox : TextBox
{
    protected override bool IsInputKey(Keys keyData)
    {
        if (keyData == Keys.Tab)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return base.IsInputKey(keyData);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyData == Keys.Tab)
        {
            this.SelectedText = "    ";
        }
        else
        {
            base.OnKeyDown(e);
        }
    }
```

and then modify InitializeComponent():

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    ...
    this.textBox1 = new TabTextBox();
    ...
}
```

[Forms.Control.isInputKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.isinputkey.aspx)

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. My textBox1_KeyDown is fired when I pressed tab key, I can see it by debugging.

Comment: Are you debugging it as part of a bigger project or did you create a new project just to reproduce the issue?

Comment: I'm debugging it as part of a bigger project. But this winform is a separate class, and it enters that line. Also, if I set each textbox as multiline and then press tab, it goes to next line within that textbox, but it just couldn't move to another textbox.

Comment: Odd, does it move to the next line within the textbox because it hit `Control.SelectNextControl`? If you remove that line of code will it still move to next line of the multiline textbox?

Comment: Is that particular textbox an instance of `System.Windows.Forms.TextBox`? I think your best bet would be to create a brand-new project and try to reproduce the issue. In a multiline textbox, pressing Tab takes me to the next control. I can't reproduce any of the issues you're pointing out.

Comment: If I remove that line of code, it still moves to the next line of the multiline textbox. Meanwhile, the boolean output of "SelectNextControl" is "false" if I use that line. So that means it just cannot select next control then. And all those textboxes are instances of "System.Windows.Forms.TextBox".

Comment: Did you create the new project and reproduce the issue in this new project?

Comment: Ok, at least I found the reason: my original project was created as "WPF Project", and I added a winform class with textboxes. But when I want to reproduce the issue, I created a "Winform Project" and so it works. Question comes as: how I can solve this in "WPF Project"? I cannot change my original project from "WPF" to "Winform Project". Could you help?

Comment: That's another post altogether. I'm no expert, but the consensus (at least from Windows Forms > WPF) is to create a new project and move all the files to this new project. I can only assume that it's equally difficult the other way around.

Comment: At least we were able to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Responding to tab buttons is handled by the message loop.  If you're running the form as modal, or are calling

```
Application.Run(myForm);
```

then you've got a message loop.  If you're only doing

```
Form myForm = new Form();
myForm.Visible = true;
```

Then you do not have a message loop and therefore tab navigation won't work.  (If you are not running the form modally, then try using the `ShowDialog()` method to show the form, and see if tabbing works in this case.)

If this is your issue, then this MSDN article below suggests that you either

1. Run each Form in its own thread (so that you can call `Application.Run(myForm)` on it).  Running each form in its own thread is a huge can of worms and should not be undertaken by the faint of heart (especially if you have preexisting or poorly designed forms).
2. [Show the dialog modally](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229591(v=vs.110).aspx).

I've had some success with a horrible hack of setting `KeyPreview` on the form to `true` and then listening for `System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Tab` within the `Form.OnKeyDown` method (and setting `KeyEventArgs.SuppressKeyPress` and `KeyEventArgs.Handled` to `true` if I do handle it).  (Also remember to check the `KeyEventArgs.Modifiers` property to see if the user is doing a [Shift]+[Tab].)  The downside of this is that you rob the Control that has a focus on the opportunity to respond to the `keypress` since `Form.KeyPreview` causes the Form to get a chance to handle the key before the Control gets a chance.  (I'm also not sure what would happen if you implemented this logic *and* had the message loop going.)

As far as what you should do when you detect the Tab Key, check out the `Control.SelectNextControl` function.  I've been calling it like...

```
e.SuppressKeyPress = SelectNextControl(
    ActiveControl, //Current Control
    true,  //Move Forward? (You want false for a Shift-Tab to go backward.)
    true,  //Only stop at controls where Control.TabStop == true?
    true,  //Consider controls nested within other controls?
    true); //Wrap to the beginning of the form if you reach the end?
```

A person who is smarter than me might be able to set up a shared message loop or something else, but this is all I've figured out so far.

Comment: your comment `Move Forward?` is incorrect, if it is set to false, `SelectNextControl` will navigate backward. this issue only happens on first control on form, if you focus a control in middle of the control stack, running `SelectNextControl`will correctly moves the focus to next control.

Answer (score 0):

Every control in windows forms application have property

```
this.button1.TabIndex = 3;
```

you can use it to select next control if you order it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If your textboxes are multiline you need to set the AcceptsTab property to false.

Comment: No, they are not multiline.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your event handler is not being registered. Make sure textboxes are not ReadOnly=true, TabStop=false.  Try this

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.textBox1.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.textBox1_KeyDown);
    }


    private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab)
        {
            textBox1.SelectNextControl(sender as Control, true, true, true, true);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Clean your project and rebuild.

Comment: Again the same. Meanwhile I tried almost all other methods that are mentioned on the internet related to this kind of problem.

Comment: Again the same. I debugged and it enters the SelectNextControl line, so did it in my original code, but then nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem with tab order completely ignored. After two hours of digging I finally found my dumb mistake: "If mybutton.Focus Then ..." when I meant "If myButton.Focused Then...". Oops. Figured I'd share in case anyone else has this experience too.